# Javascript regexp templates: only match when string inside brackets is equal

Tags: javascript, regex, templates, template-engine

I'm working with a javascript templating system for a website I'm building and I'm having a bit a of problem.

I'm using the following regex to match with sections within my string:

```
 /(\{\{(#|\^)(.*?)\?\}\}(.*?)\{\{\/(.*?)\?\}\})/
```

Feeding this a string such as:

```
 {{#is_user?}} The user is an user {{/user?}}
```

While stating "user"=true, displays the string. When "is_user" is set to false, the string is not shown. However I've found that this allows no room for nesting as such that:

```
 {{#is_user?}} The user is an user {{#has_picture?}} and has a picture{{/has_picture?}} {{/user?}}
```

This will result in the following:

```
The user is an user  {#is_user?}} The user is an user{{/user?}}
```

Thus meaning the the match is found between {{#is_user?}} and {{/has_picture?}} as the regex just checks for a match between {{#  anystring  ?}} and {{/  anystring?  }}.

Now my question is if its possible to say that there's only a match if the two strings between the brackets are equal so that a match is only found when {{#stirngA?}} {{/stringA?}}.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can make your regex only match the corresponding opening tag by using backreferences.

E.g.:

```
/(\{\{(#|\^)(.*?)\?\}\}(.*?)\{\{\/(\3)\?\}\})/
```

or without capturing all groups:

```
/(?:\{\{(?:#|\^)(.*?)\?\}\}(.*)\{\{\/(?:\1)\?\}\})/
```

The \3 (or \1) will contain the value of the first (.*?).

See it on [rubular](http://rubular.com/r/caxiYjK54Y).

But this might not fully solve your problem of nested matches. Although you could use the result and apply the regex again. Maybe thats enough for your specific case.

Comment: Thank you very much, I'll still need to test it in practice but for now it seems just its just what I needed. Also thank you for the rubular link, I was looking for something just like that.